# Adding a a new view to a view controller - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, subview

I'm working on an application, where when I press the menu button, the IBAction creates a overlay with ( add a subview ). This subview must hold buttons which must be accessible. I initially made a mistake by adding the extra buttons to the previous view. Thus when I pressed the menu button the new overlay popped out with the extra buttons not being accessible. Is there any suggestions? Im a newbie to iOS programming. Thank you

```
- (IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender
{
 UIButton* button= (UIButton*)sender;

 [self overlayCheck];

 [movingButton setHidden:false];
 [movingButton2 setHidden:false];
 [movingButton3 setHidden:false];


 [movingButton moveTo:
 CGPointMake(125,250) duration:0.8 
              option:curveValues[selectedCurveIndex]];

 [movingButton2 moveTo:
 CGPointMake(25,250) duration:0.8 
              option:curveValues[selectedCurveIndex]];

 [movingButton3 moveTo:
 CGPointMake(225,250) duration:0.8 
              option:curveValues[selectedCurveIndex]];

}


-(void)overlayCheck{

 CGRect frame = [homeButton frame];
 UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x - FrameSizeIncreaseAmount, frame.origin.y - FrameSizeIncreaseAmount, frame.size.width + FrameSizeIncreaseAmount * 2, frame.size.height + FrameSizeIncreaseAmount * 2)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


[self.view addSubview:view];


[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade in" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

[view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:MaxAlpha]];
[UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

The movingButton, movingButton2 and movingButton3 supposed to on the new view. The overlay doesn't let me access the buttons.

Comment: can you show us some code please ?

Comment: This might be because you haven't linked the buttons to the `IBAction` methods which are called upon push.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but you should add your button to your overlay view you created in the overlayCheck method:

```
-(void)overlayCheck
{
    CGRect frame = [homeButton frame];
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x - FrameSizeIncreaseAmount, frame.origin.y - FrameSizeIncreaseAmount, frame.size.width + FrameSizeIncreaseAmount * 2, frame.size.height + FrameSizeIncreaseAmount * 2)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Becareful how you set the frame X-Y coordinate
    // for your button if your moving buttons uses
    // initWithFame:CGRectMake(X,Y,Width,Height);
    //
    // The X,Y are relative to the parent view
    // that you add the moving buttons to
    // ---------------------------------------------
    [view addSubview:movingButton1];
    [view addSubview:movingButton2];
    [view addSubview:movingButton3];

    [self.view addSubview:view];


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade in" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:MaxAlpha]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```